# Java: errors, "variable species1 is already defined in method name1()"

Tags: java

I'm writing a fairly simple program just to learn the basics.
In this, the user can 'raise' a pet dragon, so it asks what species the user wants and helps with species names if the user wants help, then it asks for the name.
Then it gives a random thirstlevel to the dragon.
It was working as intended until I added the if statement and the species option.

Now I get 2 errors I can't fix:

```
Project.java:62: error: variable species1 is already defined in    method name1()           default: String species1;
                            ^ Project.java:74: error: cannot find symbol        System.out.println("Congratulations, " + name + " the " + species1
+ " has been born!");
                                                                  ^   symbol:   variable species1   location: class Project 2 errors***
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class Project {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        intro();
        String s1 = name1();
        thirst(s1);

        System.exit(0);

    }


//The following method explains what the program is for. 

    public static void intro ()  {

        System.out.println("This program allows you to keep and raise a Dragon!");

        return;
    }




//The following method allows the user to name their pet Dragon and select its species. 

    public static String name1 ()  {

        Scanner dragonSpecies = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What species of Dragon would you like to raise? You may type 'help' to get a list of existing dragon species.");    

        String species = dragonSpecies.nextLine();


        switch(species) { 
            case "help": 
                System.out.println("Anglewing: The Anglewing is a smaller dragon with golden brown oddly angled wings and bright yellow spots.");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Regal Copper: This heavyweight dragon exceeds all known breeds in sheer size (30–50 tons). Regal Coppers have vivid colorations ranging from red to yellow, and are very far-sighted.");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Malachite Reapers: Cousins of the Yellow Reapers, with yellow-brown coloring with green highlights. Prefer the cooler climates of northern Scotland and mid-size.");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Sharpspitter: A venomous breed considered too small for military use, that was cross-bred with the larger French Honneur-d'Or and the venomous Russian Ironwing to create the Longwings.");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Chequered Nettle: As a heavyweight dragon, the Chequered Nettle is very useful in battle, as they possess spiked tails that can be used in a manner similar to morning stars. The colouring a Chequered Nettle is gold with brown stripes."); 
                System.out.println("");
                Scanner dragonSpecies1 = new Scanner(System.in);            
                System.out.println("What species of Dragon would you like to raise?");  

                String species1 = dragonSpecies1.nextLine();
                break;
            default: 
                String species1;
                species1 = species;
            break;
        }


        Scanner dragonName = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What Would you like to name your pet Dragon?");

        String name = dragonName.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Congratulations, " + name + " the " + species1 + " has been born!");

        return name;  
    }



//The following method returns the thirst value of the dinosaur as a random number between 1 and 10 out of 10

     public static void thirst(String name) {

        Random thirst = new Random();


        int thirstLevel = thirst.nextInt(10) + 1;

        System.out.println(name + "'s thirst level is " + thirstLevel + "/10");

        return; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code formatting is a nightmare.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? It should highlight which variable reference is wrong

Comment: as in the indents? i started learning from an udacity course a week ago, im working on it.

Comment: im using textedit and commandprompt

Comment: As a few others have said, fire up Netbeans or Eclipse and work from a true IDE. Other than making pretty format IDE's are extremely useful for debugging.

Comment: it´s because you defined `String species1` twice inside the switch statement. An additional hint: as `species1` is a local variable inside the switch it wont be known to the `println` statment afterwards. To remove the exception define `species1` at the scope level of `name1`. Also if you are using an IDE try to use it´s automatic formating feature, because as @rmlan already said, this formatting is horrible.

Comment: I have create a edit that fix the indentation (waiting peer review at comment writing time) to make the issue more visible for any one coming on this question.  You should definitively learn how to format your code to make it more readable for you and other trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared it twice:

```
        Scanner dragonSpecies1 = new Scanner(System.in);            
        System.out.println("What species of Dragon would you like to raise?");  

        String species1 = dragonSpecies1.nextLine(); // <------------ HERE
        break;
        default: String species1;  // <------------ AND HERE
            species1 = species;
```

You don't really need a new variable here and can reuse `species`. However, should in another situation you actually need a new one, try something like

```
    String species1;
    switch(species) { 
        case "help": System.out.println("Anglewing: The Anglewing is a smaller dragon with golden brown oddly angled wings and bright yellow spots.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Regal Copper: This heavyweight dragon exceeds all known breeds in sheer size (30–50 tons). Regal Coppers have vivid colorations ranging from red to yellow, and are very far-sighted.");
      ...
        System.out.println("");
        Scanner dragonSpecies1 = new Scanner(System.in);            
        System.out.println("What species of Dragon would you like to raise?");  

        species1 = dragonSpecies1.nextLine();
        break;
    default: 
        species1 = species;
        break;
```

Comment: just let him input it in `species` again. The additional variable is quite unnecessary here honestly.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `species1` variable. It's unnecessary. Just assign and use the `species` value.

You also only need one total `Scanner` variable, not one per prompt.

In other words, remove the default case, put this line in the help case

```
species = dragonSpecies.nextLine();
```

And use `species` when you print it and the name.

Optionally rename your `dragonSpecies` to `input` or something and remove the other `Scanner` objects. Then all prompts use `input.nextLine()`